# Как повесить событие клика на элементы с одинаковыми классами?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Допустим есть несколько блоков с одинаковыми классами

```
<div class="block">Название</div>
<div class="block">Название</div>
<div class="block">Название</div>
<div class="block">Название</div>
```

И код который выполняет по событию клика какой то действие.

```
$('.block').click(function() {
$('.block').css('color','red')})
```

Как сделать так, что бы при клике функция выполнялась только для кликнутого элемента а не для всех элементов с таким же классом?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В обработке события используйте `$(this)`

```js
$('.block').click(function() {
  $(this).css('color', 'red');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">Название</div>
<div class="block">Название</div>
<div class="block">Название</div>
<div class="block">Название</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Просто

```
$('.block').click(function() {
$(this).css('color','red');
});
```